# API + grequests

Tags: python, api, python-requests, aiohttp, grequests

I have a script that sends lots of numbers, almost 27k, to our server through API then I get some info. However, I would like to send a few requests at once, is it possible through grequests? Because I've seen some examples and its kinda grequests is used to sends multiple requests to multiple URLs, but in my case, I have only one URL. I wanna send few numbers at once to decrease the time of code to end up.

My code is:

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_excel('trial.xlsx')

for number in df['index']:
    r = requests.get('https://xxx/data=%s'%number)
    print (r.text)
```

Should I use in case of one url grequests? Or maybe do you have another idea? 
Thank u

Comment: Why not just batch the numbers and have your endpoint unravel the batch and do stuff from there - rather than one request per 'number'

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use multithreading to make concurrent requests.